# data to be inserted in database through php page

Tags: php, html, mysql

```
<?php
@$code = $_POST['code'];
@$name = $_POST['name'];

@$city = $_POST['city'];

$connect = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "", "parth") or die("connection failed");

$sql_query = "INSERT INTO customer_master(customer_code,customer_name,customer_city) values(" . $code . ",'" . $name . "','" . $city . "');";
$result = mysql_query($sql, $connect);

if ($result) {
    echo "database connected";
} else {

    echo "data not inserted";
}
mysql_close($connect);
?>
```

the above mentioned code is the code of inserting the data in the database but the data in not been inserted in been displayed ,no errors are been displayed so anyone please can help me to solve the problem.

Comment: you missed single quote here ".$code." and also do not use mysql*, use mysqli* or PDO

Comment: This code is _wiiiidddeeeee_ open to sql injection attacks

Comment: *"no errors are been displayed"* – Well, you're a) actively suppressing errors and b) not checking for errors either…

Answer (score 0):

**You have made mistake over here  ".$code.", missed single quote and you are using mysql which is depreciated now so use mysqli as below :**

```
<?php

        @$code=$_POST['code'];
        @$name=$_POST['name'];

        @$city=$_POST['city'];

        $connect=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","parth")  or die("connection failed");

            $sql_query="INSERT INTO customer_master(customer_code,customer_name,customer_city) values('".$code."','".$name."','".$city."');";
            $result=mysqli_query($sql,$connect);

if($result)
    {
echo "database connected";

    }
            else
        {

echo "data not inserted";
        }
        mysqli_close($connect);


        ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've never encountered a situation where an "@" precedes a variable declaration in PHP, that's new to me but like lrvin and others pointed, you are missing a single quote in your SQL.

I'm not a fan of concatenation, I've made several mistakes trying to take the concatenation route (that's just a preference). You could follow lrvin's answer or you could also add the following modifications:

- Remove the first semicolon that is at the end of your SQL.
- Don't use concatenation
- Include mysql_error function. This would have returned an error message that would have pointed straight to your error.

  ```
  $sql_query="INSERT INTO customer_master(customer_code,customer_name,customer_city) values('$code', '$name', '$city')";
  $result=mysql_query($sql_query, $connect) or die(mysql_error($connect));
  ```

You should consider using mysqli instead of mysql. mysql has been deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

1. You are missing the single quote `'` before and after of `" . $code . "`.
2. Also Remove the Extra Semicolon `;` At the end of insert query.
   See The Code :

   ```
   @$code = $_POST['code'];
   @$name = $_POST['name'];
   @$city = $_POST['city'];
   $connect = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "", "parth") or die("connection failed");

   $sql_query = "INSERT INTO customer_master(customer_code,customer_name,customer_city) values('" . $code . "','" . $name . "','" . $city . "')";
   $result = mysql_query($sql, $connect);

   if ($result) {
       echo "database connected";
   } else {
       echo "data not inserted";
   }
   mysql_close($connect);
   ```

Answer (score -1):

Change this:

```
$sql_query="INSERT INTO customer_master(customer_code,customer_name,customer_city) values(".$code.",'".$name."','".$city."');";
$result=mysql_query($sql,$connect);
```

Into:

```
$sql_query="INSERT INTO customer_master(customer_code,customer_name,customer_city) values('".$code."','".$name."','".$city."')";
$result=mysql_query($sql_query,$connect);
```

Comment: Whilst this fixes the issue at hand it would make sense to add a hint about the usage of the totally outdated and deprecated old mysql extension and the security issues with concatenating the arguments like that.

Comment: @arkascha Why not help him first on the initial problem then when everything is fine then go encourage him to study and learn `mysqli` or `PDO`?

Comment: @Irvin Because the OP will almost certainly have no motivation to switch _after_ all issues have been sorted out and things finally work. Especially since he has to invest into understanding how to correctly quote arguments for this concatenation approach which would not be necessary at all if he were encouraged to make the necessary switch _now_.